# Run recursive grep using two patterns

Tags: linux, grep

How can I use this grep pattern to recursively search a directory? I need for both of these to be on the same line in the file the string. I keep getting the message back this is a directory. How can I make it search recursively all files with the extension `.cfc`?

```
"<cffunction" and "inject="
grep -insR "<cffunction" | grep "inject=" /c/mydirectory/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` and `exec`:

```
find your_dir -name "*.cfc" -type f -exec grep -insE 'inject=.*<cffunction|<cffunction.*inject=' /dev/null {} +
```

- `find` finds your *.cfc files recursively and feeds into `grep`, picking only regular files (`-type f`)
- `inject=.*<cffunction|<cffunction.*inject=` catches lines that have your patterns in either order
- `{} +` ensures each invocation of `grep` gets up to ARG_MAX files
- `/dev/null` argument to `grep` ensures that the output is prefixed with the name of file even when there is a single `*.cfc` file

Comment: How would I exclude recursng certain directories?

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards, you should pipe your file search to the second command, like:

```
grep -nisr "inject=" /c/mydirectory | grep "<cffunction"
```

edit: to exclude some directories and search only in `*.cfc` files, use:

```
grep -nisr --exclude-dir={/abs/dir/path,rel/dir/path} --include \*.cfc "inject=" /c/mydirectory | grep "<cffunction"
```

Comment: How would I use the --exclude to not search some directories?

Comment: If you have more recent version of grep, you can add `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,dir3}` (no whitespaces!) to the first `grep` command. If not, you'll have to combine it with `find`.

Comment: Does it need to be the full path? Or can I start from where I am?

Comment: All grep paths can be relative to the current working directory if they don't start with `/`. I've added an example of the full command above.